# Javascript: adding a dictionary to a list

Tags: javascript

I have this simple dictionary:

`var x = {'pitchName': 'pitch1'}`

```
console.log(x.pitchName)
>> pitch1
```

Now I want to create a dictionary for something like:

`{x.pitchName : 'data'}`

However that throws and error.

If I try:

`var z = x.pitchName
{z: 'data'}`

that just returns:

`{z: 'data'}`

How can I create a dictionary where the key is the value of a previous dictionary? End goal is:

`{pitch1: 'data'}`

Comment: `var obj = {[x.pitchName]: 'data'}`?

Comment: @CRice, Thanks for mentioning the computed property syntax. It was new to me.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The object literal turns the keys into strings. In your case, you want to use a variable as the key, so you need to do it in two steps:

```
var z = {};
z[x.pitchName] = 'data';
```

As CRice noted in a comment on the question, you can also use a computed property, provided you are using ES2015. More on that can be found on the MDN page for [Object Initializers](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Operators/Object_initializer). The syntax there would look like:

```
var z = {[x.pitchName]: 'data'};
```